# Cant connect to Azure SQL from Azure function

Tags: azure, entity-framework

I opened Azure Function and wanted to connect it to Azure SQL with entity frameworks (not core) code first approach,
and I cant seem to connect them successfully

I have tryied 2 conventions in my local.settings.json file

**1:**

```
"Values": {
    "AzureWebJobsStorage": "UseDevelopmentStorage=true",
    "AzureWebJobsDashboard": "UseDevelopmentStorage=true",
    "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "dotnet",
    "sqldb_connection": "{myConnectionString}"
  },
```

**2:**

```
,
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "BankContext": "{myConnectionString}"
  }
```

- BankContext is the name of context model

**Fuether more,** when im debugging it it shows me another connection string to my local MSSQL server.

Thanks alot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to provide more code details on how you are setting up your DbContext to have a more personalized answer, but I will give you the following tips:

1. Use DI as you would use in a normal .NET project with Microsoft's built-in DI container.
   You would need `Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Extensions.DependencyInjection`
   To do so, use the following configuration:

   ```
    [assembly: FunctionsStartup(typeof(Startup))]

    namespace YOUR_NAME_SPACE
    {
        public class Startup : FunctionsStartup
        {
            public override void Configure(IFunctionsHostBuilder builder)
            {
                string SqlConnection = 
                    Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("AZURE_SQL_CONNECTIONSTRING");

                builder.Services.AddDbContext<PeopleDbContext>(
                    options => options.UseSqlServer(SqlConnection));
            }
        }
    }
   ```

- Make sure you have `AZURE_SQL_CONNECTIONSTRING` locally in `local.settings.json`

2. Make sure your Azure environment is synced, otherwise, this will crash.
   To do so make sure to include the environment variable on the app service environment variables in the portal

[image]

[image]

3. Now you can use Dependency Injection to request your context, services that use the context as usual.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried it like this (an object with the property ConnectionString for the context):

```
connectionStrings": {  
    "BankContext": {  
        "ConnectionString": "{myConnectionString}",  
        "ProviderName": "System.Data.SqlClient"  
    }  
}
```

Otherwise you could read the connectionstring explicitly from the settings and provide is when calling this function on the OptionsBuilder object:

```
.UseSqlServer(Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("SqlConnectionString"));
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should configure it manually in the portal.

Go to your Azure Functions and add the Connection String with the name `sqldb_connection`.

[image: azure-function-configuration]